# Best Fit Curve and Function for 4D Data?

Tags: functions, approximation

I have experimental data of 4 dimensions, and I want to computer-generate an approximated function from that. If it helps to clarify, I'm testing a pendulum's period based on variable length, starting angle, and mass as part of a school lab report and want to find the period as a function of length, angle, and mass. And then I'd make a cool 4D graph (period = hue of color) to go with it :)

Excel has something like this for 2D functions where I only have to specify what kind of function to fit it to, such as a power or polynomial function. If this is possible, is there free software that can do this for 4D functions? Or can Excel do it?

Comment: Did you notice that the period is independent of angle and mass?

Comment: The 2pi*sqrt(l/g) formula is for a simple pendulum, and we actually have found in real-world tests that the angle and mass do affect the period for whatever reason. We're not allowed to try to bend it towards the simple pendulum formula. I haven't gotten into the reasoning yet, but my guesses are that it has to do with the pendulum not being simple due to the mass of the string, and there's friction and air resistance.

Comment: You need extreme angles (>30 degrees) before angle just might become noticeable. Increased mass would affect the length between the center of the mass and the pivot meaning you have to measure the length carefully. Friction and air resistance won't have a noticeable effect. Temperature and moisture might, but again only indirectly due to their effect on the length. (Temperature also influences a measuring device, making it more difficult.)

Comment: Again not sure why, but mass and angle definitely are affecting it in our case. The materials used aren't very high-end, so friction might be substantial. We tested angles from 5˚ to 50˚ inclusive, masses from 50g to 1000g, and recorded the tests with a 120FPS camera and checked the times down to hundredths of a second in QuickTime Player.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this using Excel (not without some programming, anyway). Mathematica or Matlab would probably be better. Neither is free, but educational copies are fairly inexpensive.